# Wi-Fi soft handoff using more antennas and long cables?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, android

I have to organize a show in an underground car park. I have:

- 1 car running fast in the parking lot;
- 1 Android smartphone in the car;
- the Android smartphone has to connect with a PC in real time, without delays or packet loss;
- also PC is located in the underground parking;

There is no internet or 3G access.

The best way to communicate between smartphone and PC is using wifi. The car park is divided by internal walls, a single access point does not cover the entire car park. I have 2 options:

1. using a range extender or 2 access points with the same SSID
2. using 200 feet cables rp-sma for my wi-fi antennas (I have a Netgear R7000 AC 1900 with 3 antennas); I place the antennas in different zones

With solution 1) I can't have a soft handoff and I lose packets during wi-fi handoff. So the only option is the second one.

Questions:

- Can I get a soft handoff with this solution?
- Should I use high gain (directional) antennas instead of original one?
- How works the 3 antennas in these routers? Does they do the same job or they do different jobs?

Comment: 200 ft cable is going to have a very measurable impact on cabling losses (on both transmit and receive) at 2.4 GHz. Exactly how much depends very much on the type of cable but you can probably expect to lose a few tens of dB of signal strength.

Comment: Thank you Michael. If I use shorter cable, 100 feet cables ultra low loss, do you think my idea could work? That is, if I put the 3 antennas in 3 different zones/rooms in the parking, do you think I can get a soft handoff (that is I never miss wifi connection)? And should I replace standard antennas with high gain ones or should I leave standard ones?